# How to cast IntPtr to byte*

Tags: c#

I'm calling a method via interop that returns an `out IntPtr` parameter. How can I get a `byte*` for this `IntPtr` so I can operate on it? I tried the following:

```
fixed(byte* ptr = (byte)myIntPtr)
```

but it didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Dmitri, could you either request more informations, or accept an answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
byte* ptr = (byte*)int_ptr;
```

You don't have to use the *fixed* keyword. You don't want to pin the IntPtr, do you?

Comment: This also works fine, though personally I like the ToPointer method, especially if you don't need immediately to convert it to a specific type pointer (e.g. from void* to byte*).

Answer (score 8):

`myIntPtr.ToPointer()`

Comment: Note that the fixed keyword isn't really appropiate in this case as it is used to prevent relocation of variables. Since IntPtr is already a (managed) pointer, you essentially just want a direct conversion between the two types. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21(VS.71).aspx

Comment: IntPtr in this case is *not* a managed pointer, rather an unmanaged pointer!

Comment: Yeah, what I really meant is that IntPtr is a managed pointer in the sense that it's part of the managed libraries, whereas byte* is an unsafe C-style pointer. Perhaps "safe" would be a better word, though it's important to note the difference between IntPtr and SafeHandle.

Comment: IntPtr isn't very safe either, seeing as you can cast it from/to integers. Anyway there are lots and lots of legacy APIs to work with, so IntPtr isn't going away anytime soon.

Comment: Well yes, it's quite fundamental to Win32 interop programming. I think I made the point the IntPtr isn't very safe (depending on which sense of the word you use) - but at least it does not require an unsafe context as pointers do.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't want "unsafe code" in my application, so I did the following to convert an IntPtr to a byte[]. Given an IntPtr called "unsafeDataBlock":

```
var byteArray = new byte[dataBlockSize];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(unsafeDataBlock, byteArray, 0, dataBlockSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work for me, I wasn't using Interop but was still calling a managed C++ function from C Sharp. The managed C++ function however called unmanaged code so it accomplished the same thing as Interop.

Anyway, in the C++ function that was called from c-sharp, I used this code:

```
(anyPointerType*) pointer = (anyPointertype*) myIntPtr.ToPointer();
```

Comment: Just to clarify what I meant by:
"
I wasn't using Interop but was still calling a managed C++ function from C Sharp. The managed C++ function however called unmanaged code so it accomplished the same thing as Interop.
"

calling unmanged code through Interop:
C-Sharp -(Using Interop calls)> unmanaged code
has the same result as
calling from c-sharp a managed c++ function that calls unmanaged code:
C-Sharp -(Calls)> Managed C++ function -(Calls)> unmanaged code

and the latter procedure is usually much easier

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want unsafe code in your application, you'll have to use the methods in `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`, or (even better) declare your interop functions' parameter types so the marshaling happens automatically.