# C# how to get Byte[] from IntPtr

Tags: c#, byte, arrays, intptr

I have a .dll(not my own) that has a delegate. This delegate Callback function is:
"CallBackFN(ushort opCOde, **IntPtr payload**, uint size, uint localIP)"

How can i convert IntPtr to Byte[]? I think that payload is actually Byte[]. If it's not Byte[] and it's something else would i lose some data?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298930/how-to-get-byte-from-intptr-in-c

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you looked into Marshal.Copy?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx

Answer (score 73):

If it's a `byte[]` array:

```
 byte[] managedArray = new byte[size];
 Marshal.Copy(pnt, managedArray, 0, size);
```

If it's not `byte[]`, the size parameter in of Marshal.Copy is the number of elements in the array, not the byte size.  So, if you had an `int[]` array rather than a `byte[]` array, you would have to divide by 4 (bytes per int) to get the correct number of elements to copy, assuming your size parameter passed through the callback refers to the number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is it. If the array is not byte then i will try to change the "size"

Comment: +1 for the first half of the answer. Really, the other half doesn't ... I haven't even read it :)

Answer (score 25):

If you need performance, use it directly:

```
unsafe { 
    byte *ptr = (byte *)buffer.ToPointer();

    int offset = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<width; j++)
        {

            float b = (float)ptr[offset+0] / 255.0f;
            float g = (float)ptr[offset+1] / 255.0f;
            float r = (float)ptr[offset+2] / 255.0f;
            float a = (float)ptr[offset+3] / 255.0f;
            offset += 4;

            UnityEngine.Color color = new UnityEngine.Color(r, g, b, a);
            texture.SetPixel(j, height-i, color);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

According to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713324/how-to-cast-intptr-to-byte/1304570#1304570), you can do the following:

```
var byteArray = new byte[dataBlockSize];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(payload, byteArray, 0, dataBlockSize);
```

Comment: where we get the dataBlockSize value?

Comment: @Parthi - That depends on what you're doing. The block size is going to be different depending on how much data you're copying.

Answer (score 9):

`Span<byte>` may be a better solution as it provides most features you need from a byte array. It is faster as you won't need to allocate and copy to a new buffer and safer as you will not have to use directly the pointer.

```
IntPtr ptr = ... ; 
int ptrLength = ...; 


unsafe
{
    Span<byte> byteArray = new Span<byte>(ptr.ToPointer(), ptrLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++ )
    {
        // Use it as normalarray array ;
        byteArray[i] = 6;
    }

    // You can always get a byte array . Caution, it allocates a new buffer
    byte[] realByteArray = byteArray.ToArray();
}
```

It's included in.NET Core 2.1 and a [nuget package (System.Memory)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) for .NET Framework 4.5 + and .NET Core 2.0 +;

Comment: Are you quite sure the ToArray() here does not cause an allocation? In my testing, it seems to.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that ToArray causes an allocation and copies the content
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.toarray?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Marshal.Copy Method (IntPtr, Byte[], Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx)