# IntPtr to Byte[] Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, typeconverter

I have an IntPtr (c#) given from unmanaged code. I know that this is an reference to an Byte Array with 4096 elements.

Now i want to CONVERT these data from IntPtr to Byte[] WITHOUT Marshal.Copy. Because the memory in kernel space is already allocated. I only want to interprete those data as an byte array.

I know that there a function "InteropUtils.ConvertIntPtrToByteArray-Methode" but it is only available for smart Devices etc.

Maybe somebody had an better idea?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713324/how-to-cast-intptr-to-byte/1304570#1304570

Comment: @DavidG i thought you didnt read my question. I DONT want to use the Marshal.Copy() method.

Answer (score 0):

What you asked is not possible because an IntPtr represents an **unmanaged** memory region, while a byte[] array represents a **managed** memory region. It is not possible to treat an unmanaged region as a managed one.

You must either copy the data to a managed region (through Marshal.Copy), or use an unsafe code to manipulate it directly.